# Windows domain auhentication in Oracle with usernames longer than 30 symbols

Tags: windows, oracle, authentication

We use windows domain authentification to connect our users to Oracle. Most of the time it works fine.
But we ran into unexpected problem.
Some usernames are longer than 30 symbols. So the syntax

```
CREATE USER OPS$SomeVeryLongDomain/SomeVeryLongLogin IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY
```

just don't work.

(**os_authent_prefix** has a standard value OPS$).

Is it possible to use domain authentification for usernames longer than 30 symbols?

**UPD**
There definitely is a [workaround](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asokerb.htm#ASOAG9647) for Kerberos authentication.

> If the user's Kerberos principal name is longer than 30 characters, and up to 1024 characters, then create the user as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE USER db_user_name IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY AS 'kerberos_principal_name'
```

> For example:

```
SQL> CREATE USER KRBUSER IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY AS 'KerberosUser@EXAMPLE.COM';
```

But I cannot understand how to use the method for OS authentification and is it possible at all.

Comment: At the max you could save 4 more characters by setting `os_authent_prefix = ""` and get rid off the prefix `OPS$`, but in the end you can't go beyond 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

> os_authent_prefix has a standard value OPS$

Well you can't go beyond 30 characters as that is the limit. Read [External Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admnauth.htm#i1006459).

The **os_authent_prefix** parameter affects how Oracle matches a Windows username to an Oracle username when you're not using Windows group membership. Early versions of Oracle used a prefix of `OPS$`, which you would append to the beginning of the Oracle username used in external authentication. Because Oracle usernames are limited to **30 characters**, using an `OPS$` prefix effectively limited the username to the remaining **26 characters**. To avoid using the OPS$ prefix, the Oracle database parameter file, the init.ora file (in the \%ORACLE_HOME%\database folder), should have the following setting (default Oracle9i and Oracle8i installations are configured to include this setting):

```
os_authent_prefix = ""
```

The parameter is provided for backward compatibility. Oracle doesn't recommend adding a prefix, thus the default empty setting is as shown. For a change to the **OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX** setting to take effect, you must shut down and restart the Oracle database instance.

Comment: Saw your update. I never had to do that. Also, there are several steps to achieve it per the documentation. And how would you get to know the number of characters. What if they go beyond 1024?